# Accessing values of google endpoints API block objects inside ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-endpoints

I have coded a backend on google appengine API which is working (checked with API explorer).
On executing my API, I should get multiple products returned.

The ios code below works and I confirmed NSLog dumps all the objects.

```
GTLServiceTicket *apiCall = [shoesService executeQuery:shoesQuery completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLProductApiManyProduct *object, NSError *error)
 {
         NSArray *receivedItems = [object items];

         NSLog(@"%@",receivedItems); // this works shows objects with all propeties and corresponding values

         // This is apparently an error, xcode wont allow this even when typing
         NSLog(@"Product id:%@", [[receivedItems objectatIndex:0] productId]);

         //Type casting also does not work in either case below.

         NSLog(@"Product id:%@", (GTLProductOneProduct *)[[receivedItems objectatIndex:0] productId])

 }
 ];
```

I think the issue is because all the properties have be autodeclared as @dynamic

How do I access properties inside the GTLProductOneProduct class of the returned *object?
If your api receives blocks of products (GTLProductAPIManyProducts) which contains (GTLProductAPIOneProduct), how do you access the values inside GTLProductAPIOneProduct ??

Comment: `objectatIndex` should be `objectAtIndex`. Is that a copy/paste error or your actual code?

Comment: @martin just copy pate error on objectAtIndex. The issue is how to access the object properties.

Answer (score 0):

Should have dug more before putting this question on.

Used a wrong typecast now working, thanks all.